Fine-tuning pretrained model on 2 tasks with 2 labeled dataset
I am having difficulty using BERT for a sentiment analysis task that handles both aspect-based sentiment analysis (ABSA) and comment sentiment analysis. I know that using two separate classification layers on top of the hidden layer can classify these two tasks, but I don't know how to handle labels for these two datasets. One dataset only has sentiment labels (positive, negative, and neutral), while the other includes 10 aspects with 4 sentiment labels (including NONE for aspects that are not present). I am wondering if I can assign a task type to the data and use it to identify which task is being trained on the model. Please let me know your thoughts on this problem. Thank you for your help! Have a good day!!!!!
I want to train the model on both combined datasets simultaneously, so the model's output can handle both tasks: aspect-based sentiment analysis (ABSA) and comment sentiment analysis (CA)
